# A problem in using theorem for finding limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Let $a_n = \arctan ( \ln n )$ , find $\lim_{ n \to \infty} a_n$ if any . I think we can't apply the theorem (i.e $\lim_{ n \to \infty} \arctan ( \ln n ) = \arctan (\lim_{ n \to \infty} \ln n) = \pi /2 )$ . The condition of theorem is $a_n \to L$  but here $a_n$ diverges to infinity . Although , we know that $\pi / 2$ is the right answer since $\lim_{x \to \infty} \arctan x = \pi /2  $ and instead of $a_n$ we can put any other sequence that diverges to infinity .

Comment: $\pi/2$ is not the right answer??

Comment: Just set $u=\ln n$ and perform substitution in the limit.

Comment: No , $\pi / 2$ is the right answer .

Comment: $\{a_n\}$ is an monotonic increasing sequence, it is bounded above and $\frac {\pi}{2}$ is the least upper bound.

Comment: The usual substitution theorems also work for the case when $L$ is $\infty$. Thus if $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) =A$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x) =\infty$ then $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(g(x)) =A$. Such variations of the usual limit theorems may not be explicitly mentioned in books, but they are in general true unless stated otherwise. Thus for example the above rule also works if $A$ is replaced by $\infty$ or $-\infty$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Yes you're right , thanks .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since 
$arctan(x)=\pi/2-arctan(1/x)$
and $arctan(x) \to 0$
as $x \to 0$,
if $f(n) \to \infty$
then
$arctan(f(n))=\pi/2-arctan(1/f(n))
\to \pi/2$.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are correct and that you cannot use that theorem (which would require arctan to be continuous at infinity. You have touched on another way to do this in the end of your comment; In particular, using the sequential characterization of limits.

Since $\lim_{x \to \infty} \arctan(x) = \pi/2$, we know that $\arctan(x_n)\to \pi/2$ for any $x_n \to \infty$. Since $\ln(n) \to \infty$ we are done.

Answer (score 1):

Since $b_n=\log n \to +\infty$

$$\lim_{n\to +\infty} a_n = \lim_{n\to +\infty} \arctan ( \ln n )= \lim_{b_n\to +\infty} \arctan ( b_n )=\frac{\pi}{2}$$